# Undefined $_SCRIPT variables when executing php from a scheduled task

Tags: php, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, undefined, superglobals

Thank you for your time in advance.

I have a php script that is supposed to run once daily. We set up a scheduled task on the client's server and it executes a batch file that essentially calls the following:

```
php-cgi.exe -d short_open_tag=On ".\my_script.php"
```

If I navigate directly to my_script.php via the browser everything works fine. When I execute the batch script from either the command line or via a scheduled task I'm given multiple errors.

1. The last run result of the task scheduler is always "(0xFFFFFFFF)".
2. The first error from the command line is "Notice: Undefined index: DOCUMENT_ROOT".
3. The second error from the command line is "Notice: Undefined index: SCRIPT_NAME".

Lines giving errors:

```
$document_root = $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ];
$_SERVER[ 'FULL_URL' ] .= $_SERVER[ 'SCRIPT_NAME' ];
```

If I var_dump() the $_SERVER variable I see both the DOCUMENT_ROOT and SCRIPT_NAME are there and populated properly. I have the scheduled task running with highest privileges under the SYSTEM user.

What can I do to stop these errors from the command line and the scheduled task?

Comment: `$_SCRIPT`? Did you mean `$_SERVER`? Also, error report generally has line number included, it would be better if you can show relevant lines.

Comment: @Passerby Thank you for catching that. I'll add the relevant lines.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you ask me, when you run it in command line, there's no server, so I doubt that most entries in `$_SERVER` will be missing. Try `var_dump()` _in command line_ to see what you can get.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When calling the batch file from the stored procedure I incurred errors but when I called php-cgi.exe directly and added my arguments to the arguments textbox everything ran perfectly.

I'm guessing my batch file didn't have the proper permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `php.exe` or `php-win.exe` instead of `php-cgi.exe`.  See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php) for details of differences between the SAPIs.

But note that the `$_SERVER` superglobal is populated differently at the CLI than it is by a web server. (My installation returns an empty string using `php.exe`.)

If you want to get the current file path use `__FILE__`.  For the current directory use `__DIR__`.

A quick test for you to try; this should return the current directory:

```
php -r "echo __DIR__;"
```